# Is there a better way to draw multiple points in SFML?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

I am trying to draw every pixel on an 800 by 800 window with a random color, and I am drawing the pixel using `sf::Vertex`, but when I run the program, it is very slow. Is there a better way to draw multiple points that is faster and uses less memory? Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <ctime>
#include <random>


int main() {
    // Window
    sf::RenderWindow window{ sf::VideoMode{ 800u, 800u }, "Views" };
    sf::Clock clock;

    static std::mt19937 randomEngine{ static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(nullptr)) };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> randDist{ 0, 255 };

    // Main game loop
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // Event loop
        sf::Event sfmlEvent;
        while (window.pollEvent(sfmlEvent)) {
            if (sfmlEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        // Draw
        for (float i = 0; i < window.getSize().x; ++i) {
            for (float j = 0; j < window.getSize().y; ++j) {
                uint8_t r = randDist(randomEngine);
                uint8_t g = randDist(randomEngine);
                uint8_t b = randDist(randomEngine);
                sf::Vertex pixel{ { i, j }, { r, g, b } };
                window.draw(&pixel, 1, sf::Points);
            }
        }

        // Display
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen `sf::Image`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to one of the comments, I now know how to fix this problem.

Instead of using a bunch of `sf::Vertecies`, I could use a `sf::Image`. What I did was that I created an image the size of the window and made it all black. Then instead of drawing each individual point, I set each of the pixels in the image to a random color. Then, after exiting the for loops, I loaded the image into a texture and used set that texture to a sprite that I drew onto the window.

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <ctime>
#include <random>


int main() {
    // Window
    sf::RenderWindow window{ sf::VideoMode{ 800u, 800u }, "Views" };
    sf::Clock clock;

    static std::mt19937 randomEngine{ static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(nullptr)) };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> randDist{ 0, 255 };

    sf::Image image;
    image.create(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y, sf::Color::Black);
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    // Main game loop
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // Event loop
        sf::Event sfmlEvent;
        while (window.pollEvent(sfmlEvent)) {
            if (sfmlEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        // Draw
        for (float i = 0; i < window.getSize().x; ++i) {
            for (float j = 0; j < window.getSize().y; ++j) {
                uint8_t r = randDist(randomEngine);
                uint8_t g = randDist(randomEngine);
                uint8_t b = randDist(randomEngine);

                image.setPixel(i, j, { r, g, b });
            }
        }

        texture.loadFromImage(image);
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        window.draw(sprite);

        // Display
        window.display();
    }
}
```